# Vue devtools inspection is not available on locally hosted app

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, yarnpkg, vue-devtools

When I run my Vue app, the Vue devtools extension detects Vue.js, but complains:

> Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author.

I'm serving the app locally using `yarn serve`, which runs `vue-cli-service serve`.

```
vue: 3.0.0
vue devtools: 6.0.12
@vue/vue-cli: 5.0.1
@vue/vue-cli-service: 4.5.14
node: 16.14.0
yarn: 1.22.4
Chrome:  98.0.4758.102
```

Vue devtools **DOES** work if:

- Another dev runs the app in Chrome from a clean local repo (same versions of everything above)
- I create and run a new Vue app (vue create) in Chrome

Vue devtools **DOES NOT** work (same error message) if:

- I run my app from a new local repo
- I clear all browsing data from Chrome
- I add `vue.config.performance = true` to my `main.ts` file
- I add `--mode=development` to my `vue-cli-service build` command
- I use Edge (Chromium) instead of Chrome
- I update vue to 3.0.14
- I access the app via `http://localhost:8080` or a hosts file alias `https://myalias:8080`

AFAIK I never did anything to force a production build or disable vue devtools, so I'm stumped why it doesn't just work out of the box. What am I missing?

[UPDATE]

- .env files have only `VUE_APP_*` variables defined.
- Vue is installed locally (not using CDN version).
- vue.config.devtools is not available in vue3. [vue.config.performance](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-performance) appears to be the replacement.
- Using the Vue devtools beta (6.0.0.21) does not help.

[UPDATE 2]
I upgraded all matching packages in my project to match the versions in the new Vue app for which the dev tools were working. The dev tools are now working on my app, but I don't know which package upgrade did the trick. Would still be nice if the Vue owners could provide more insight into why this occurs and how exactly to fix it.

Comment: can you show us your .env file? or which command do you start with your application?

Comment: you can find some useful answers [here](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/190)

Comment: Try `Vue.config.devtools = true`, It should work

Comment: Vue.config.devtools is not available in vue3

Answer (score 2):

Install Vue force dev extension.

Answer (score 1):

For my situation, go to Chrome's `More Tools > Extensions > Vue.js devtools > Details`, and switch on the `Allow access to file URLs` option. Finally it works for me again.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have explicitly defined mode `NODE_ENV` in a local .env file
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Having that would completely explain the behaviour you're experiencing and also why it works as expected on other machines.

Comment: I have `.env`, `.env.development`, and `.env.production` files, all included in the repo so they are the same on any machine. `NODE_ENV` is not defined in any of them. The only variables defined in them are `VUE_APP_*`.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is that you have NODE_ENV defined in your shell, try running `echo $NODE_ENV` in the shell where you run `yarn serve` and see if it prints out anything?

Comment: nope, NODE_ENV is not defined